# Configure list & grid view in Angular Routing

Tags: angularjs, listview, gridview, angular-ui-router

So I'm working on a website that currently populates the page with cards in a Grid format [3x3]. I've been asked to provide the option to change the view to a list. So now I have two view files, list-view.html & grid-view.html.

The website is using Angular routing to load pages and I'm having a hard time configuring the paths to the correct view files.
Below are snippets/screenshots of the code I'm working with:

```
<div align="center">
    <button class="btnView"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>  List</a></button> 
    <button class="btnView"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> Grid</button>
</div>
```

### This code above creates the buttons in "index.html"

```
var app = angular.module('leavesNext', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.tab.scroll','ngSanitize','ngCookies','720kb.socialshare'])

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/?tag',
    templateUrl: 'views/card-view.html',
    controller: 'homeController'
})

.state('search', {
    url: '/?search',
    templateUrl: 'views/card-view.html',
    controller: 'homeController'
})
```

This snippet about is that "script.js" that loads the home page. Any ideas on how I can go about loading the respective files when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ### Activating a state
>
> There are three main ways to activate a state:
>
> - Call `$state.go()`. High-level convenience method. [Learn More](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)
> - Click a link containing the `ui-sref` directive. [Learn More](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)
> - Navigate to the url associated with the state. [Learn More](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

For more information, see [UI-Router Wiki - Activating a State](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#activating-a-state)